# Prove that, if $(a)=(a')$, then $a'=ua$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be integral domain. Show that if $2$ principal ideals $(a)$ and $(a')$ are equal (where $a,a'\in R$) then there exists $u\in R^{\times}$ such that, $a'=ua$

Now if $(a)=(a')$ then $a\in(a')$ and $a'\in(a)$ therefore there exists some elements $u,v$ in $R$, such that $a=ua'$ and $a'=va$, which implies that $a=uva$.

Hence $uv=1$ and $u$ is a unit, $u\in R^{\times}(=R\setminus\{0\})$

but I didn't make use of the property that, $R$ is an integral domain, so $R$ can be any ring or not ?

Comment: "... Hence $uv=1$ ..." -- you did use it

Comment: @orangeskid sorry but I don't see it, what else could $uv$ be in a normal ring ?

Comment: The implication $a=uva\implies uv=1$ is not valid in just any ring $R$. It needs to be a ring $R$ with no zero divisors. An integral domain does not have any zero divisors....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated that $a=uva$ implies $uv = 1$.  This is the cancellation law which holds in integral domains (but not for any ring).

To prove this for integral domains, note that if $ca=cb$ for $c \neq 0$, then $c(a-b)=0$ so $a=b$.

A counter-example for a ring which is not an integral domain is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, where $2 \cdot 1 = 2 \cdot 3$.

Comment: @Harry Lang we use first the commutativity; $a=uva=auv$ and then distribution law $a(1-uv)=0$ and finally the fact that $R$ has no zero divisor, so $uv=1$ ?

Comment: @gebruiker thanks - that was a typo - I meant Z/4Z

Comment: By the way, the case $a = 0$ needs to be dealt with separately (as it is the argument isn't OK).

Comment: @Najib Idrissi Is then $(a)$ zero ideal, since it is pricipal ? If that is true then we obtain $0=uv0$ and for $u\in R$ the equality holds, right ?

Comment: @inequal: If $a = 0$ then $(a') = (a) = (0)$ and therefore $a' = 0$ too. In particular $a' = 1 \cdot a$.

Answer (score 1):

The implication $a=uva\implies uv=1$ is not valid in just any ring $R$. It needs to be a ring $R$ with no zero divisors. An integral domain does not have any zero divisors....

So your proof is almoast complete it just needs one extra line:

> Now if $(a)=(a')$ then $a\in(a')$ and $a'\in(a)$. Therefore there exist some elements $u,v$ in $R$, such that $a=ua'$ and $a'=va$, which implies that $a=uva$.
>
> **Since $R$ is an integral domain, this implies $uv=1$**, etc...

Comment: Is my comment under Harry Lang's answer correct ?

Comment: Yes. The key thing is that you mention the fact that we have no zero divisors.